# How to get path directories list in portable way in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, path, portability

[`path` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html) returns path as a long concatenated string, separated by platform-dependent separator

Is it possible to obtain list of directories in path in portable way?

---

Currently I write:

```
function [ res ] = pathdirs(  )
%PATHDIRS Returns all path dirs as a cell array of strings
    p = path;
    if ispc
        sep = ';';
    else
        sep = ':';
    end
    res = strsplit(p, sep);
end
```

can it be done better?

Comment: "Portable" meaning "with the proper _separator_", or "paths _relative_ to a base folder"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platform-dependent separator is [`pathsep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pathsep.html).

```
function res = pathdirs
%PATHDIRS Returns all path dirs as a cell array of strings
    res = strsplit(path, pathsep);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about processing the path to make it portable:

```
myPath = path;
myPortablePath = strsplit(myPath, ';');
```

Using above code, `myPortablePath` is a cell array with each cell containing individual directories.